# After deploying site on azure decrease in response time and increase in database CPU usage

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-elasticpool

We have Azure-based SQL server in the elastic pool and our application is connected to it. Today, I deployed my .net core Web API on my personal desktop (not even on the server) and response time and CPU usage I can see is much better. When the same application I deployed on Azure server (App service), I saw huge utilization of CPU even 100% for some request. I am a little curious why this is happening? even when we have database server on azure only in both the case. Is there anything wrong which I am doing.

P.S: each request have a bulky operation (inserting 100k records or comparing thousands of spatial points)

Comment: Probably locally you have few cores lots of memory, but when you deploy to azure you can have 1 or 2 cores. I would say the problem is somewhere in the code. Without context its like look in coffee and try to predict future :)

Comment: In addition because of cold start first request will use lots of cpu. and so on

Comment: I am new to Azure.Can you please help me to check from where I can check the number of cores for Azure server

Comment: In pricing model it should say how much memory and how many cores

Comment: Now getting an error "Elastic pool limit is set to 100 and has been reached" with just 11 continuous users for my GPS tracking app. Any help, please my client will kill me otherwise